# Merging two list of hashmap using Java8 Stream API

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have two `List`s of `HashMap`:

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> a = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
List<HashMap<String,String>> b = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

Sample data:

```
a = [{a1=1, b1=2, c=3},{a2=4, b2=5, c=6}]
b = [{d1=7,c=3},{d2=8,c=6}]
```

I want to merge the two `List`s and have a final `List` of `HashMap` using Stream API having output:

```
c = [{a1=1, b1=2, c=3, d1=7},{a2=4, b2=5, c=6, d2=8}]
```

Any help?

Comment: What if there's a conflict?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the Stream API is not the answer. In this case a regular loop would be much more readable and maintainable. You could even add comments in the loop to explain why it does something without making the code unreadable. Stream API makes mundane things very easy and complicated things even more complicated.

Unless it's a homework assignment in which case it's a stupid homework assignment. School work shouldn't encourage students to use stupid constructs in wrong places.

In the real world readability and maintainability are paramount to line count or cleverness score.

Answer (score 1):

If you merge them according to the `List`s' index, and both `List`s have the same length, you can write:

```
IntStream.range(0,a.size()).forEach(i->a.get(i).putAll(b.get(i)));
```

This will result in `List` `a` containing the merged result.

If you want to produce a new `List` without mutating the original `List`s, you can create new `HashMap`s and collect them to a new `List`:

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> c =
    IntStream.range(0,a.size())
             .mapToObj(i -> {
                        HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<>(a.get(i)); 
                        hm.putAll(b.get(i)); 
                        return hm;
                      })
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT for the updated question:

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> c =
    a.stream ()
     .map(am -> {
             HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<>(am);
             HashMap<String,String> second =
               b.stream()
                .filter (bm -> bm.get ("c") != null && bm.get ("c").equals (am.get ("c")))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
             if (second != null) {
               hm.putAll (second);
             }
             return hm;
          })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now we stream over the elements of the first `List` and for each `HashMap`, search for the corresponding `HashMap` of the second `List`.

Comment: I want to have internal hashmap merging on key "c". See my updated question. Can you please help me?

Comment: @AnitaPatel does it mean, for example, that the first HashMap from list a could be merged with the second HashMap from list b?

Comment: Yes. First HashMap from list a could be merged with the second HashMap from list b by key "c" having same value.

Comment: @AnitaPatel and what if multiple HashMaps of the same list have the same value for key "c"?

Comment: Data have surety. That case will not raise.

Comment: Perfect! I appreciate your help  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. To simplify it I defined a Bifunction.

```
BiFunction<HashMap<String, String>, List<HashMap<String, String>>, HashMap<String, String>> biFunction =
            (m1, listOfMap) -> {
                HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<>(m1);
                listOfMap.forEach(item -> {
                    if (item.containsKey("c")&& item.get("c").equals(result.get("c")))
                    result.putAll(item);
                });
                return result;
            };
```

then to merge use this BiFunction to merge List items.

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> biFunction.apply(list.get(i), list2))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```